# White space on layer update in 360 degree viewer - Leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

Good afternoon everyone!

I am trying to build a 360 degree viewer with zoom control. For that, I´m usig Leaflet. Everything works fine but layer update. 
To change folder´s image container, I´m updating layer´s url, but in this change a white space appears for a while (few ms). I´ve been looking on Leaflet docs, internet, and trying on my own, but i´m unable to solve this. 
Does anyone know any possible solution?

Thanks everyone for helping me!

PD: I can´t also give you images, but ím working with TileLayers.

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>

        <link href="style/jquery-ui.css"rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="style/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="style/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.4/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </head>
    <body>

        <img src="img norman foster/header.PNG" id="img_header" />

        <div class="threesixty visor" id="image-map"></div>

        <div id="slider"></div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <a class="btn custom_previous"><img src="src/images/rotateleftbutton.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Girar hacia la izquierda" /></a>
            <a class="btn custom_next"><img src="src/images/rotaterightbutton.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Girar hacia la derecha" /></a>
        </div>

        <img src="img norman foster/footer.PNG" id="img_footer" />

        <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.4/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="js/L.TileLayer.Zoomify.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = init;

            var map = "";
            var layer = "";
            var oldSrc = "";
            var newSrc = "";
            var gui = "";
            var path = "";
            var imgcounter = 1;
            var extension = "_img/";
            var layers = new Array(80);

            function init() {

                oldSrc = './360/TNFF_0PO6055M_001/TNFF_0PO6055M_001-001_img/';
                gui = oldSrc.indexOf("-");
                path = oldSrc.substr(0, gui + 1);

                getFiles();
                //SLIDER
                $(function() {

                    $("#slider").slider({
                        range : "min",
                        value : 1,
                        min : 1,
                        max : 80,
                        slide : function(event, ui) {

                            var photonumber = ui.value;

                            if (photonumber >= 1 && photonumber < 10) {
                                photonumber = "00" + String(photonumber);
                                newSrc = path + String(photonumber) + extension;
                            } else {
                                newSrc = path + "0" + String(photonumber) + extension;
                            }

                            oldSrc = newSrc;
                            imgcounter = parseInt(photonumber);
                            src = newSrc;
                            leafleft();
                        }
                    });

                });

                //BUTTONS
                $('.custom_previous').bind('click', function(e) {
                    changeimageLeft();
                });

                $('.custom_next').bind('click', function(e) {
                    changeimageRight();
                });

                //LEAFLET
                map = L.map('image-map').setView([0, 0], 2);

                layer = L.tileLayer.zoomify(oldSrc, {
                    width : 8688,
                    height : 5792,
                    minZoom : 1,
                    maxZoom : 4,
                    attribution : 'LBNV',
                    unloadInvisibleTiles : true
                }).addTo(map);

                var southWest = map.getBounds().getSouthWest(),
                    northEast = map.getBounds().getNorthEast(),
                    bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
                map.setMaxBounds(bounds);

            }

            //URL CHANGE
            function leafleft() {

                layer.setUrl(newSrc);
                oldSrc = newSrc;
            }

            //LEFT BUTTON
            function changeimageLeft() {

                if (imgcounter == 80) {
                    imgcounter = 1;
                    newSrc = path + "00" + imgcounter + extension;
                } else if (imgcounter >= 1 && imgcounter < 10) {
                    imgcounter++;
                    if (imgcounter == 10) {
                        newSrc = path + "0" + imgcounter + extension;
                    } else {
                        newSrc = path + "00" + imgcounter + extension;
                    }
                } else {
                    imgcounter++;
                    newSrc = path + "0" + imgcounter + extension;
                }
                common();
            }

            //RIGHT BUTTON
            function changeimageRight() {

                if (imgcounter == 1) {
                    imgcounter = 80;
                    newSrc = path + "0" + imgcounter + extension;
                } else if (imgcounter >= 1 && imgcounter <= 10) {
                    imgcounter--;
                    if (imgcounter == 0) {
                        imgcounter = 1;
                        newSrc = path + "00" + imgcounter + extension;
                    } else if (imgcounter == 9) {
                        newSrc = path + "00" + imgcounter + extension;
                    } else {
                        newSrc = path + "00" + imgcounter + extension;
                    }
                } else {
                    imgcounter--;
                    newSrc = path + "0" + imgcounter + extension;
                }
                common();
            }

            function common() {

                layer.setUrl(newSrc);
                oldSrc = newSrc;
                $("#slider").slider('value', imgcounter);
            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The white screen transient that you see when changing the URL template of your [Zoomify Tile Layer](https://github.com/turban/Leaflet.Zoomify) is very probably due to how Tile Layers (including the one from Zoomify plugin) behave when changing their URL: they redraw all their tiles using the new URL template, so there is a short duration when there is no image present.

You could mitigate this behaviour by simply using several Tile Layers and swapping them, instead of re-using the same one and changing its URL template. Then you would have like a Layers Control, but with your "Left" and "Right" buttons instead of one radio per layer.

However, you might still have a transient when the previous layer is swapped by the new one, so you might include a delay before actually removing the previous layer from the map.

Comment: I supposed that white space was due to url change, but trying myself other ways like preloading images, problem stayed. However,I will try your solution. Thanks for helping me!! I will answer when finish it

Comment: I´ve created some tile layers, but how can I emulate the Layers Control? I mean, I tried before adding and removing layers, and behaviour was the same

Comment: Done it!! There are two methods, bringToBack and bringToFront. Loading all layers on webpage load, you can use both to show or hide layers, however, thanks for your attention and your reply

Comment: Np. Just pay attention to a potential hit in performance if you actually have all your layers added to map and just show one with `bringToFront()`. Since you actually have many layers, the map may become a little bit slow on poor HW.

Comment: I´m showing only one layer of 80 (which has 5 layerGroups per generated folder whith zoomify) . Problem appears when zooming. Map freezes on every zoom, or crashes. I´ve been looking for a solution, but I have not found it yet.